# Visualforce Chart length of Bar

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

I am trying to use Visualforce charting(bar chart)  and my problem is I want control the length of the bar.

Wondering how to increase the visual length of bar.
Any suggestions please..!!!

[image]

Comment: When you say length of bar, do you mean how far out the bar comes in the chart?  If so, you need to reduce the values on the lower axis as your bars are short because they are just around 10.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Lower axis dynamically calculating and rendering.. wondering how to get the control on length of bar..

Comment: The length of the bar is correct though - if you made it longer then it wouldn't reflect the actual value would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added maximum and minimum value in .

That solved my problem!

[image]

Comment: Arun -- you should mark this as answered and post the snippet of VF code into your answer to hep others

Answer (score 2):

Use width attribute followed by integer and percentage

```
<apex:chart name="MyChart" height="300" width="450" data="{!data}"..
```

Comment: An example of this ?

Comment: <apex:chart name="MyChart" height="300" width="450" data="{!data}".I'm not sure.This is an idea

Comment: Editing that into your answer above directly will surely improve the quality and help to other users.

Comment: Sure i'will make a note.